# How can I push data to an array inside a promise then?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I've been trying to figure out. How I can push a result to an array from a promise loop. Can anyone point me in the right location?

```
const ids = [1, 2, 3]
let results = []

for (let id of ids) {
    getLight(id)
        .then(light => {
            results.push(light)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}
```

Comment: Are you using bare promises or something like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) which has helper methods? What you want is something like [`Promise.reduce`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html) to convert those `ids` to an array of `light` records.

Comment: the code is ok. The one thing though: you have to access the results after all promises resolve (use `Promise.all`)

Comment: @marzelin it *might* be ok, the results are not necessarily pushed sequentially. It might resolve getLight(2) before getLight(1)

Comment: That's the correct way. Please explain why do you say that it doesn't work (it isn't doing what you expect? error messages? exceptions?) and show the code for `getLight()`, because if that doesn't work, the problem may be in there. `light` would be the value that is passed to the resolve method of the `Promise`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3]
let results = []

Promise.all(
  ids.map((id) =>
    getLight(id)
    .then(light => {
      results.push(light)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  )).then(() => console.log(results))

function getLight(id) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(res, 1000)
  }).then(() => `light for id: ${id}`)
}
```

with async/await

```js
(async() => {

  const ids = [1, 2, 3]
  let results = await Promise.all(
    ids.map((id) =>
      getLight(id))
  )

  console.log(results);
})()

function getLight(id) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(res, 1000)
  }).then(() => `light for id: ${id}`)
}
```

Comment: This is much more verbose than necessary, and there's no need to store `results` as a module-level variable. See my answer.

Comment: @Greg my goal was to make the code work with as little modifications to OP code (so it is easier to understand by OP)

Answer (score 5):

Promises are asynchronous, so you can't do that. You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) though to compose the promises together and then wait on the result:

```
const ids = [1, 2, 3]
Promise.all(ids.map(id => getLight(id))).then(results => {
  // do something with results here
})
```

Breaking this down:

1. `ids.map(id => getLight(id))` converts the ids to an array of *unresolved* promises.
2. `Promise.all(promises).then(results => { ... })` resolves all the promises and passes the results (in the correct order) to the callback