# Array.push() not working with Mongoose Populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, asynchronous, mongoose

I read another post about this issue, but I was unable to figure out how to apply it to my situation ([node js Array.push() not working using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971967/node-js-array-push-not-working-using-mongoose))

This is my Mongoose async populate function, what I want to do is push a value to a final array which includes each review which I will later do something with. However .push() does not work and I always get an empty array; From what I have read it has to do with the for loop being synchronous and not being able to accept async values but im unsure on what to do to fix it

```
  //Empty array will be populated with all scores
  const allReviewsRating = []
  this.populate("reviews").then(async function (allReviews) {
    for (const review of allReviews.reviews) {
      allReviewsRating.push(review.rating)

    }
    // async.map(review, allReviews.reviews)

  })
```

But even when I do something like this

```
  const allReviewsRating = []
  this.populate("reviews").then(async function (allReviews) {
    allReviewsRating.push(`1`)
    for (const review of allReviews.reviews) {
      allReviewsRating.push(review.rating)

    }
    // async.map(review, allReviews.reviews)

  })
```

The final array is empty which confuses me even more

I was wondering what I need to do in order to get my array to not be empty, and actually have the values I want it to have

Comment: `const allReviewsRating = []` is at the wrong place. It belongs inside of `async function (allReviews) { ... }`

Comment: I did not include the entire code, but the async function is actually in a normal synchronous function which returns something; I can't return it from the async function since it would return a promise which the code can't handle, so it needs to be outside the async function

Comment: That's not possible. You can't eat a Pizza *(now)* that will be delivered in an hour.

Comment: I read a few other posts, they say I need to use Promise.all() for it to work but I need to know where to wrap the Promise.all(), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156282/how-can-i-push-data-to-an-array-inside-a-promise-then

Comment: JS is not magic, it can not manipulate time. That's what you're asking for. Your synchronous function *can not be synchronous!* It has to return a Promise and the code calling it has to deal with it.

Comment: But if I make the function async my values will be messed up, so im unsure on what to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253088/discussion-between-commoq-and-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check, `this.populate()` function that is not populating `reviews` and if it's populating then the issue is in this `allReviews.reviews` reviews are not in allReviews. Everything else is working. I tested it on my system.

Comment: Sorry I did not really understand this, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: From where you are populating `reviews`?? I think, that is not populating properly or that is returning an empty array in `allReviews`.

Comment: No the population works fine, its when I push to an array in the global scope when it doesn`t work.

Comment: Can you please send here a reference array of populated data?

Comment: Here is an example:

`{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "642ea4c76f7a8de6a7d7fe32"
  },
  "body": "Nice (:",
  "rating": 3,
  "author": {
    "$oid": "642dc09d31cd33421acb1e74"
  },
  "__v": 0
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `.lean()` in your query or do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(allReviews))` then push data in array.

Comment: Where do I put the .lean()?, and when is Parse and Stringify I get **allReviews is not iterable**